# Cannot change Dynamic Web Module to 3.1 when using Spring boot 2.1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm creating a web application with **Spring boot 2.1.1**.
As soon as I add Spring boot 2.1.1 dependency, the **Dynamic Web Module** changed from **3.1** (the version I need) to **4.0.**

What should I do to set Dynamic Web Module to **3.1**.

I tried to edit **org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml**, clean and update maven dependencies, but the Dynamic Web Module come back to 4.0.

I suppose there is a child dependeny in **Spring boot 2.1.1** that force the Dynamic Web Module to be **4.0**.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just get that the problem depends on Spring boot 2.1.1 dependencies. It has some java libraries versions that can't "run" with a lower version of Dynamic Web Module 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Boot version 2.2.4.
I changed: `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`
under my project folder.
was:`<installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>`

to:`<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>`

But always that I execute maven update I have to change it again.
**Before change I close my eclipse.**